# Create Django slug method

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I just started using Django for some time now and i stuck trying to work with slug. I know what they are, but it's dificult for me to define a simple slug and display it on my browser.

Here is the scenario: i've a models.py containing a class book with 3 fields: name, price and Autor. I want to retunr a slug string for name and autor with only hyphens (-) and lowercase letters.

My question is how to achieve this. Using only the model, the views and the html. This is what i've got till now. But don't know how to get it displayed on my browser(`localhost:8000/book_name`)

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    autor = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return 'app:book', (self.slug,)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
```

Add the following to your model:

```
def save(self,*args,**kwargs):

  self.slug = slugify(self.name)
  return super(Book,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Then you can use the slug in your urls:

```
url(r'mybooks/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.BookDetailView.as_view(),name='book_details'),
```

Views:

```
from django.views import generic

class BookDetailView(generic.DetailView):

   template_name = "templates/book_detail.html"
```

Comment: And how do i call it to the url? I'm suppose to modify my urls.py file?

Comment: so i edited my urls.py as describe, but nothing happend: 127.0.0.1:8000/book_details

Comment: Do you have a BookDetailView and a template?

Comment: I've a templage file containing my html. But no BookDetailView

Comment: updated, but you should really pick a tutorial and take 2-3 hours to get into django

Answer (score 0):

You may add this to your models.py file:

```
def save(self , *args , **kwargs):
    if not self.slug:
        self.slug=slugify(self.name)
        super(Book, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

It worked for me.